# i am Unable to fetch the user id of logged in user from my data base

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to get the user id to display the profile details of logged in user but i am unable to fetch the id Here is my code in login page

```
 $email =   mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $q = "select * from users where email = '$email'";
     $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
     $id = $rows['$id'];

   $result = mysqli_query($con, $q);

   $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if($num == 1){
   $_SESSION['user'] = $email;
   header("location:home.php?id=$id");
   }else{ 
   $reg = "insert into users(email)  values ('$email')";
   mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    header('location:index.php?msg');
  }
```

Here is my home page code

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
 header("Location:index.php"); 
 exit; 

 
}
 $id = $_REQUEST['id']; 
 include_once('conn.php');
 $query="select * from users WHERE id= '$id' "; 
 $result=mysql_query($query);

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you appended the `$id` from your login page to `home.php?id=$id` and then in your home.php file, you are trying to fetch that $_GET['id'] value.

Here are the things to help you debug.

1. First check if from your loginpage that upon successful login you are redirected to home.php?id=$id. Then check the URL if you have correct id
2. Use $_GET['id'] instead. You can try to `echo $_GET['id'];` to see if there's any value.